# struts2 passing parameters

Tags: struts2

New to Struts2.

1. I have a search criteria form(search1) ,where I have dropdown lists to submit to get a result page (consolidatedreports.jsp).
2. In my result page, I am showing the data from the search criteria, but I also have a form at the top of the results page with search2 criteria to submit again.
3. I am chaining my actions because the heading for the results page needs a value from the search1 criteria to determine a heading value.

This works

**Question**

1. Now I want the heading to change when I use the search2 form in the results page.
2. How can I use the values from the search criteria in the search1 and override search2 values in the results page when a user chooses new criteria to run a new report on the results page?

I am modifying someone's code so it has to be done like this.

Can someone suggest a link so I get some information?

Comment: i am not able to understand your question properly.can you rephrase it and some jsp code can also help a lot

Answer (score 0):

please clarify your question...

Using the search criteria and the value which you have entered in your first search page go to your action class.

There you have to check what are your search criteria.

Based on the criteria your codes for selecting values will be get differentiated.

That is you have to use if else if or some switch for each case according to your criteria.

Then in each case you have to bind your values into a list(if it is a server side coding.) and return the control to forwarding 2nd search page.

If it is a client side coding, you just need to return to 2nd page.

In the second page at top you can put your search boxes as in 1st page. then you can get the values from the list and print them, if its server side coding.

If its client side coding, get the selection value for criteria from action page ,  find the results using your calculations. print it..

the same action class can be used for your second page's search field also..

while submitting the form, keep a hidden field which will specify the name of your page, so that we can identify which search criteria is printing result, using that value you will be able to change your header values also.

Comment: I was chaining my actions and that was good because I needed one of the search criteria of the first page to determine the heading for the result page.  The search criteria in the result page still had the values from the previous page.  When I tried to change the values and resubmit - the same values from the previous page were showing.  The form wasn't getting the new values I selected.

Comment: just edit you question, specify what you have done what output you are getting, etc. using some code fractions etc.